# 3-day rolling log return in R

Tags: r, xts

I'm trying to figure out a smart way to calculate 3-day rolling return for a large group of stocks. I'm not used to work with xts objects and I hope that some of you guys are, because I would love to use the PerformanceAnalytics package on my data.

[3D rolling return formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYdpN.jpg)

I'm having a large xts object with 559 stocks and 10 years of daily prices. Is there a smart way to keep the structure of the xts object and save the rolling return? Preferably without a for-loop.

```
> dim(Prices)
[1] 2610  559
```

Comment: I used a double for-loop itterating over stock and days, and manually binding dates onto afterwards.. I would like to do it more elegant.

Comment: can you share a small subset of the data or can you create some dummy data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The diff() function might help me.

```
# Generates Dummy Data
set.seed(100)
dates <- seq(as.Date("2010/1/1"), length.out=20, by="day")
R <- as.xts(rbind(c(0,0,0),matrix(runif(n=57, min = -0.1, max = 0.1),nrow=19)),order.by=dates)
colnames(R) <- c("St1","St2","St3")
prices <- 100*apply(1+R,2,cumprod)

# Calculating log-returns
logR3d <- diff(log(prices), lag=3)

# Check calculations
logR3d_calc <- as.xts(matrix(NA, nrow = 17, ncol = 3 ),order.by=dates[4:20])
colnames(logR3d_calc)=c("St1","St2","St3")

for (stock in 1:ncol(prices)){
  for (day in 2:(nrow(prices)-2)){
    logR3d_calc[day-1,stock] <- sum(log(1+R[day:(day+2),stock]))
  }
}
```

Comment: Another option is `TTR::ROC`: `logR3 <- TTR::ROC(prices, 3)`

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out